# apache not posting form data from subdirectory file with mod rewrite rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, scope

Stumped here. Is there some file structure 'variable scope' concept that I need to understand when using Mod-rewrite?

I have a file structure like so

/modules/modulename/index.php  ( this file imports an include file form_inc.php
/modules/modulename/form_inc.php

If I post back to same file /modules/modulename/index.php  there is NO post data available.

If I post to a file in the root domain there is post data. ???

I should note, the index file in the structure is a real file but it was called from index.php at the root. so basically I have SEF URLS that are handled from the root index.php.  But I wanted a php file in my modules folder to handle the form. All this worked before I tried adding SEF URLS.

ex. 
www.mydomain.com/contact-us/form  includes a form from /modules/contactform/index.php  that form's action is attempting to use /modules/contactform/process.php but there is no post data! but there is post data from the root index.php which is my main 'router' file. If i put my process.php file in teh root it works. Not where I want that file however.

Here's my mod-rewrite rules

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /orientation_dev
RewriteBase /

#if the file exist pass it on thru and exit.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1 [L]                

#if the file NOT a directory redirect to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Thanks for any insight on this!

Answer (score 0):

Found this code which seems to fix my POST DATA issue. I think that my Post were being redirected as well which I did not expect by the previous mod rewrite rules.

```
  # 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
  # include a trailing slash
  # except for form POSTS

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L,NE]

    # Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
    # but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,NE]
```